# node.js rest server not restarting after crashes (upstart)

Tags: node.js, unix, express, init, upstart

I have a **node.js rest server** and I wanted to run it as a daemon and **make it re-spawn when it crashes**.

I have very limited knowledge of unix, so I just tried several example scripts I found on Google. The one below seems to work, **except it doesn't re-spawn the app, when it crashes and doesn't log the actual error most of the time**.

Can you tell me what is wrong with it?

```
#my-app                                                                           
description "node.js my-app"                                                  
env FULL_PATH="/home/ec2-user/rest-api"                                              
env NODE_PATH="/usr/local/bin/node"                                                     


start on filesystem or runlevel [2345]                                            
stop on [!2345]                                                                   

script                                                                            
   export HOME="/ec2-user"                                                           
   export NODE_ENV=development                                                    
   echo $$ > /var/run/rest.pid                                                 
   cd $FULL_PATH 
   exec $NODE_PATH index.js >> /var/log/rest.sys.log 2>&1                     
end script                                                                        

pre-start script                                                                  
    echo "[`date`] (sys) Starting" >> /var/log/rest.sys.log                     
end script                                                                        

pre-stop script                                                                   
    rm /var/run/rest.pid                                                        
    echo "[`date`] (sys) Stopping" >> /var/log/rest.sys.log                     
end script                                                                        

respawn limit 50 30   
#respawn tried this as well with no success
```

I have put this code in a **/etc/init/rest.conf**

**I'm running it like this:**

```
$ sudo start rest
rest start/running, process 7734
```

The number (7734) is different each time I run it, if that is of some importance.

The log at **/var/log/rest.sys.log** has output regarding the starting of the daemon:

```
[Mon Apr 20 22:32:18 UTC 2015] (sys) Starting
Express server listening on port 3000 in development mode
[Thu Apr 23 13:26:28 UTC 2015] (sys) Starting
Express server listening on port 3000 in development mode
```

However, most of the times it stops, there is nothing about the crash itself, but for some cases it does. For example, when the mysql server was down, the node.js app stopped and logged an ECONNREFUSED error in /var/log/rest.sys.log

**index.js:**

```
var config = require('./config');
var domain = require('domain');
var d = domain.create();
var server = require('./server');

d.on('error', function(err) {
  console.error(err);
});

d.run(function() {
  server.start();
});
```

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express')
    app = express(),
    routes = require('./routes'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    methodOverride = require('method-override'),
    errorHandler = require('errorhandler'),
    path = require("path"),
    applicationRoot = __dirname,
    router = express.Router(),
    config = require('./config')
var winston = require('winston');
require('winston-papertrail').Papertrail;
var url = require('url');

var logger = new winston.Logger({
    transports: [
        new winston.transports.Papertrail({
            host: xxx,
            port: xxx
        })
    ]
  });

var db = require('./db')

app.use(bodyParser());
app.use(methodOverride());
app.use(express.static(path.join(applicationRoot, "public")));
app.use(errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));


app.use('development', errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));
app.use('production', errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));

[...]

function start() {
    var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
    app.listen(port);
    console.log("Express server listening on port %d in %s mode", port, app.settings.env);
}
exports.start = start;
exports.app = app;
```

**My system info:**

```
NAME="Amazon Linux AMI"
VERSION="2014.09"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2014.09"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux AMI 2014.09"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:amazon:linux:2014.09:ga"
HOME_URL="http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/"
Amazon Linux AMI release 2014.09
```

Comment: FYI, rather than build your own system to restart your node app, you could use an existing solution such as [forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever).